# Suppose two sets of 2 elements, $\{x_1, x_2\}$ and $\{y_1, y_2\}$ are uniformly and independently chosen from the set of integers ${1, . . . , r}$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

Suppose two sets of 2 elements each, $X = \{x_1, x_2\}$ and $Y = \{y_1, y_2\}$ are uniformly and independently chosen from the set of positive integers ${1, . . . , r}$. What is the probability that the sets $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint?

Comment: It doesn’t matter what $X$ is. Once it’s been chosen, $Y$ will be disjoint from it if and only if $Y\subseteq[r]\setminus X$. How many $2$-element subsets of $[r]\setminus X$ are there? How many $2$-element subsets of $[r]$ are there? (Here $[r]=\{1,\ldots,r\}$.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: suppose $x_1, x_2$ are fixed. How many ways are there to choose $y_1, y_2$ so that they are not equal to $x_1, x_2$?